# Modal windows in React

Tags: reactjs, modal-window

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hQ95.jpg) you can see my code in React.js

I want to have several modal windows in one React component. I tried to use Modal from “react-native”, but it didn’t work.

Now I’m trying to use my own realisation of modal window, you can see it here. I want to use this component for creating modal windows according to parameters.

Unfortunately, this component creates modal windows with default values (null). I have watched lots of tutorials, but I still don’t know how to fix it.

I will be very grateful for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asume that you are passing some value to `title`.
You can add some [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) operators in the `jsx` structure:

```
<div className="modalTitle">{title ? title : "what ever value you want"}</div>
```

Or you can add/set loader:

```
return (
      <>
        {title ? (
          <div>Your modal content here</div>
        ) : (
          <div>Your loader here</div>
        )}
      </>
      );
```